# Locating script in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

Can someone help me with the code to locate this element in selenium (java)? I need to locate it and get the text.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var _kc={"ticket":"","currency":"EUR","market":"RO","customerData":"8","oddsFormat":"decimal","locale":"en_GB","streamingAllowedForPlayer":true,"racingMode":false,"playerId":"","enableFreeBets":false};
</script>
```

Screenshot: [image]

I want to use AssertEquals in order to check if this script is present into the webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the text from script text using :

```
 String scriptText =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='InnerContentDiv']//script")).getAttribute("innerText");
```

and after that you can use this text for assertion.

Comment: Hi dangi, I ve used this text for assertion but it fails.I ve declared another string (abc) with the same value ( value copied from the the print ) and still fails.Any ideea pls?

Comment: what is the another text with which you are validating this script text. You can ping me at sandpdangi13@gmail.com

Comment: please check your mail for solution.

Comment: Sorry for answering late. Still not working .I have an error  after import  org.apache commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils. The method unescapeJavaScript(String) is undefined  for the type StringEscapeUtils . StringEscapeUtils got deprecated

Answer (score 0):

You can try the cssSelector to get everything inside this 'scipt' tag, something like the following and then assert the text:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.InnerContent > script")).getText();
```

Use it as is or modify driver.findElement according to how you have defined your object or pageFactory etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
String script = "//script[contains(.,'{\"ticket\":\"\",\"currency\":\"EUR\",\"market\":\"RO\",\"customerData\":\"8\",\"oddsFormat\":\"decimal\",\"locale\":\"en_GB\",\"streamingAllowedForPlayer\":true,\"racingMode\":false,\"playerId\":\"\",\"enableFreeBets\":false};";
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath(script));

assert(elements.size() > 0); // if size > 0, there is a script with given value
```